# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I have tried everything to get my localhost to run for my php server. Nothing works. i have watched so that the Apache is running, also that it's running to the right port.

I really would love some help here! I am providing as much as information I can. The thing is that i got it to work at some point, and then I upgraded to MOJAVE and then everything went to bust.

My problem is when i want to open my index.php at 
http://localhost/index.php i get the

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I found this in my Apache log file:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 245 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   DocumentRoot '/Users/pontus/Sites' is not a directory, or is not
>   readable

Here is some more info

```html
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
<IfDefine SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 8080
</IfDefine>
```

```html
#LoadModule session_cookie_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module libexec/apache2/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule slotmem_plain_module libexec/apache2/mod_slotmem_plain.so
#LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule dialup_module libexec/apache2/mod_dialup.so
#LoadModule http2_module libexec/apache2/mod_http2.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
##LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module libexec/apache2/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module libexec/apache2/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule dav_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module libexec/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module libexec/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule asis_module libexec/apache2/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module libexec/apache2/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module libexec/apache2/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module libexec/apache2/mod_imagemap.so
#LoadModule actions_module libexec/apache2/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module libexec/apache2/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
```

```html
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

```html
DocumentRoot "/Users/pontus/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/pontus/Sites">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Where are you getting this message? At some log, or when you request it? From what i know, first of all your conf is missing ServerName directive and what port it's listening just to name a few.

Comment: When im trying to open the file in webbrowser, how do i check what port it's listening to? And what do you mean when you say my conf is missing ServerName @Marco

Comment: when you type http://somedomain.com it is same as http://somedomain.com:80,  so the default port is 80. For https default port  is 443.

Comment: The Apache error you posted pretty much says it all. I doubt seriously Apache is actually running and listening on port 80 given that error.

Comment: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded.. That means it's running right?

Comment: I don't know but I've never known Apache to start with a syntax error like that in its configuration file. The connection refused error you are getting would tend to back up my guess that it isn't really running.

Comment: Well let's say i have really screwed up my terminal, what is the best thing to do here? Do i need to reboot the whole computer lol!!!!!!

Comment: Have you verified that that directory exists and that the Apache user has access to it?

Comment: Oh i see what you mean...I tought it was created cause it shows in the terminal...How do i find if it exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the potential port issue.

It looks like you need to add this to the listen section:

```
 <IfDefine !SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
     Listen 80
    </IfDefine>
```

What you pasted shows the alternate port if Server.app is running.

Then restart Apache in terminal:

sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

Second, the directory issue:

If you are using the Apache server that comes with Mojave, see if the default Webserver directory is there by using Finder Go->Go to Folder or ls -l in terminal:

/Library/WebServer/Documents

If it is, change the directory to the default location in /etc/apache2/http.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"   
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

Then restart Apache in terminal:

sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart

Now go to localhost in a browser, and if all is well, it will say "It works!" (assuming the original index.html is there). If that happens, move your php scripts to /Library/WebServer/Documements and make sure permissions are correct. To do that, you'll want to become familiar with 'ls -l', 'chmod', 'chown', and 'chgrp'.

Comment: I tried it, but now i get Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Comment: It sounds like we're getting closer. I have modified my answer a bit to hopefully include the added information you need.